# Why do rebels travel with X-Wings?

Tags: star-wars

Just reading "Skywalker Strikes" it seemed strange that you would choose a X-Wing as means of transport.   I mean I get that Luke kinda ended up with one in Ep 5.  But in the Marvel comics it became his standard transport.  I think there were more pilots in comics and books.  In Force Awakens also Poe travels with a X-Wing.

It strikes me strange.  The X-Wing doesn't seem to offer much - mostly very little space and no room for passengers.  Also in combat a singular X-Wing doesn't seem much of a threat.  Especially being a signature rebel craft it seems strange to take this for undercover trips.

Was this ever addressed?  And is there a rationale?

Comment: Is it a signature rebel craft? I though it was just a comercially available craft (unlike for example tie fighters which are not for sale)

Comment: Also, Luke apparently traveled to Ach-To in an X-Wing (which either crashed into the ocean or sunk somehow).

Comment: Considering that they let some kid fly one of the like, nine x-wings they had in their darkest hour, they must be a little short on pilots. So they buy the best single-seater fighter available. [Xwing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-65_X-wing_starfighter): 4 guns, a "complement of proton torpedoes", shields, hyperdive, plus an astronomic droid slot. TIE fighter: 2 guns (full stop). X-Wings don't seem much of a threat against what now?

Comment: @Mazura I know the X-Wing is a decent craft - but most star fighters are deployed in number.  I don't recall a X-Wing holding its ground like something heavier - like the Falcon would.

Comment: @bdecaf - you mean like holding its ground against a Death Star? Or Starkiller base? Or (if you treat flying video games as canon) numerous capital ships?

Comment: @bdecaf - If you have to fight a Star Destroyer, your *covert* mission has probably failed in its covertness.

Comment: Why do people travel in their own, small, uncomfortable car when they could as well take the bus, or better yet train or plane? Easy: Independence and cost.

Comment: @Polygnome the question is more why the X-Wing is almost exclusively assigned/chosen for this task. To stick with your example almost all people ride cars with more than one seat just because they like the extra room and flexibility that comes with it at almost no cost - so why pick something with a strict one seat limit?

Comment: @bdecaf Practicality? In most cases, the extra seat is not needed. The X-Wing is readily available, another ship might not be. The pilot is in most cases very familiar with the X-Wing. If you have a smart with 2 seats and are used to driving it, why take a 4 seater SUV you are unfamiliar with? just because it has two more seats you do not need anyways?

Comment: @Polygnome essentially I'm looking for any text passage or dialogue confirming this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Poe wasn't expecting his ship to be seen and it's small enough that he can conceal it entirely (at least in the script and novel, in the film it's just sitting out in the open like a gigantic "come kill me" beacon).

> So far, the mission had gone by the book. **He had slipped into Jakku’s
> atmosphere under cover of darkness and concealed his X-wing under a
> dense outcropping of rock.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Additionally, we learn in the [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know, Updated and Expanded](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know,_Updated_and_Expanded) edition that Poe's X-Wing has been sprayed with a special paint that makes it difficult to detect on sensors.

> **HOW IS POE'S CUSTOM X-WING DESIGNED FOR STEALTH MISSIONS?**
>
> *The orange and black ferrosphere paint scatters First Order scanners!*

---

As a small, fast, stealthy and highly reliable ship that can run blockades with relative ease and that has an independent hyperdrive capability, it makes a pretty decent vessel to use for a covert insertion mission.

Comment: For me this begs the question - why don't we see the other star fighter models used in similar fashion.  Say the A-Wing with its higher speed and smaller size would be a good option as well.  On the other hand Han manages to conceal the falcon in several occasions so I wonder if small size is that important.

Comment: @bdecaf - Poe likes X-wings. So he uses an X-Wing.

Comment: That comment is the right answer. They like _their_ x-wing, so they fly _their_ x-wing

Comment: I wouldn't like to fixate on Poe.  I can roll with the pilots being allowed to chose the craft they like. My question aimed more  in the direction was this practice ever mentioned or even explained - in canon or otherwise.  Maybe I'm still in the wrong mindset - I keep thinking how it would be if an Airforce pilot/agent would take his F18 for a trip to - say somalia.

Comment: @bdecaf - it's highly unlikely that Poe's attachment to his X-Wing is unusual.  The X-Wing is manufactured by the same company as, and is apparently very similar to, the [T-16](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-16_skyhopper/Canon), which is the ship that many pilots (including Luke) first learn to fly in -- that familiarity may well make them more comfortable in it than other ships that are less similar.

Comment: On the F18 comparison... first F18s are Navy, not AF. Second, not really, this is more like a Pilot dispatched on a diplomatic mission behind enemy lines, where going in fast and small is the best defense. The X-Wing provides that, along with challenging threats if the mission goes hot. Why would he take a shuttle (Helicopter analogous?) for the same job when it's only him? These space fighters also seem to require less maintenance than Earth planes, and don't need specialized runways.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of traveling in an X-Wing versus being on a transport and then hopping into an X-Wing is that when exiting hyperspace, the pilot is already ready to go and fight without having to prepare to launch. This gives hyperspace-capable starfighters like the X-Wing a level of tactical flexibility that other starfighters can't match. The Last Jedi supports this, since Poe's X-Wing is destroyed, along with the rest of the Resistance's fighter corps, before being able to launch. Since travel in Star Wars doesn't seem to take that long (<1 day for many distances, like the Raddus to Canto Bight, which Finn thought was a far away destination), so comfort wouldn't be too big of an issue.